# Indexing pandas dataframe to return first data point from each day

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

In Pandas, I have a DataFrame with `datetime`s in a column (not the index), which span several days, and are at irregular time intervals (i.e. not periodic). I want to return the first value from each day. So if my `datetime` column looked like:

```
2013-01-01 01:00
2013-01-01 05:00
2013-01-01 14:00
2013-01-02 01:00
2013-01-02 05:00
2013-01-04 14:00
```

The command I'm looking for would return the dataframe columns for the following indexes:

```
2013-01-01 01:00
2013-01-02 01:00
2013-01-04 14:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this setup:

```
import pandas as pd
data = '''\
2013-01-01 01:00
2013-01-01 05:00
2013-01-01 14:00
2013-01-02 01:00
2013-01-02 05:00
2013-01-04 14:00'''
dates = pd.to_datetime(data.splitlines())
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'val': range(len(dates))})

>>> df
                 date  val
0 2013-01-01 01:00:00    0
1 2013-01-01 05:00:00    1
2 2013-01-01 14:00:00    2
3 2013-01-02 01:00:00    3
4 2013-01-02 05:00:00    4
5 2013-01-04 14:00:00    5
```

You can produce the desired DataFrame using `groupby` and `agg`:

```
grouped = df.groupby([d.strftime('%Y%m%d') for d in df['date']])
newdf = grouped.agg('first')
print(newdf)
```

yields

```
                        date  val
20130101 2013-01-01 01:00:00    0
20130102 2013-01-02 01:00:00    3
20130104 2013-01-04 14:00:00    5
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. I was working with groupby and aggregate, but didn't know about the 'first' option. Thanks.